# How to build share screen using react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

My app is more like a *note taking app* with different folders to organize notes. Now, using **React-Native**

1. I need to add my app to the share widget to the of other apps when they select a text content. (apps like browsers, other notebook apps etc.)

[image]

2. I need to build the UI to share when users click on share button to share some text content from other apps as shown below

[image]

Can I do this with the react stuff? Or do I need to do something with XCode or Android Studio ?? Any Code reference is helpful.

most preferred platform: **iOS**

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension

Comment: Thanks, @SouravGanguly Do I definitely use a package ??

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with built in react native API called [Share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html). No need to install any package. Here is example:

```
_shareMessage() {
  Share.share({
    message: 'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React'
  });
}

_shareUrl() {
  Share.share({
    message: 'A framework for building native apps using React',
    url: 'http://facebook.github.io/react-native/',
    title: 'React Native'
  });
}
```

> You need to import `Share` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu) package. It is exactly what you need.